# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '...aa53' - Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a django project and I am trying to save something into my database from a json response. The field in the table is a charfield. the returning response is a string. I want to simply save the response in the database by create a new database object. I am getting the following error an I am not sure why this is happening.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5..6003463aa53'
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
for node in nodes:
node_json = node.json
node_id = node_json['_id']
print(node_id)
node_name = node_json['info']['nickname']
print(node_name)
node_class = node_json['info']['class']
print(node_class)
node_bank_name = node_json['info']['bank_name']
final_bank_name = str(node_bank_name)
print(node_bank_name)
new_account = SynapseAccounts.objects.create(
     user = currentUser,
     name = node_name,
     account_id = node_id,
     account_class = node_class,
     bank_name = final_bank_name,
)
print(new_account)
```

I even forced the string.

Here is the model that I have for the table:

```
class SynapseAccounts(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Bank Account')
     account_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     account_class = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Checking')
     bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='DefaultBank')
     create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/yap/opentab/tab/views.py", line 1859, in saveLinkedAccounts
    bank_name = final_bank_name,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 962, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1106, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1058, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 998, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 770, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5a00e02cf9bd86003463aa53'
```

Comment: Please fix indentation, and add full stack trace.

Comment: you can look at it above @scharette

Comment: The IDs in your JSON are apparently in hexadecimal format.  You'd need to explicitly convert them to integers:  `account_id = int(node_id, 16)` perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, that your `account_id` field (`account_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)`) is receiving data that is not an integer.

Are you sure that `node_json['_id']` returns an integer? because you use that value to setup `node_id` that is then used on create for the `account_id` field.

Note: `5a00e02cf9bd86003463aa53` looks like an `id` but not an Integer one.

Comment: ok so it is the id not the bank name. i got it that makes sense. thanks @dethos